# Mudar conteúdo da modal

Tags: php, html

Eu tenho este html:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando clico em `saiba mais`, uma modal é aberta com as informações de acordo com o plano.

O html e o conteúdo da modal é basicamente este:

```
<div id="abrirModal" class="modalDialog">
    <a class="close" title="Fechar" href="#fecharModal">X</a>
    <div class="modal">
        <div class="description_service">
            <span class="title_modal"><?php echo $title_modal; ?></span>
            <span class="text_modal"><?php echo $text_modal; ?></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Os dois são iguais, o que muda é o conteúdo (título e texto).

Então para não precisar criar duas modals diferentes, quero saber como posso fazer para que: Quando clicar em saiba mais do Plano 1, o conteúdo seja do Plano  1, e que quando clique no Plano 2 logicamente abra com o conteúdo do Plano 2.

Qual seria a maneira mais fácil de fazer isso?

*PS: A modal é gerada apenas com CSS*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando jQuery ou Javascript você pode passar o conteúdo das modais para uma função dentro do link do '*saiba mais*':

```js
function funcao(conteudo, titulo) {
  $("#titulo").html(titulo);
  $("#conteudo").html(conteudo);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><a href="#" onclick="funcao('$bodyModal1', '$tituloModal1')">saiba mais1</a></p>
<p><a href="#" onclick="funcao('$bodyModal2', '$tituloModal2')">saiba mais2</a></p>

<div id="modal">
  <p id="titulo"></p>
  <p id="conteudo"></p>
</div>
```

Se não puder usar jQuery ou Javascript você pode trazer as modais já montadas no PHP, por exemplo:

```
<?php
$conteudos = //buscar no bancou ou outro lugar
for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($conteudos); $i++) {
  $modais[$i] =
   '<div id=\"abrirModal\" class=\"modalDialog\">
    <a class=\"close\" title=\"Fechar\" href=\"#fecharModal\">X</a>
    <div class=\"modal\">
        <div class=\"description_service\">
            <span class=\"title_modal\">' . $conteudo[$i]["titulo"] . '</span>
            <span class=\"text_modal\">' . $conteudo[$i]["conteudo"] . '</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>'
}
?>
```

E no HTML apenas imprimir as modais:

```
<?php
echo $modais[0];
echo $modais[1];

// Ou com for mesmo //
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

### Aconselho utilizar Jquery:

1 - Crie um evento para cada saiba mais sendo identificado por um ID:
 `$('#saiba1').click( function() {....`

2 - Use função html() ou  text(), dependendo do conteúdo para acrescentar:

```
$( ".title_modal" ).html( "<?=$title_modal_1?>" );
$( ".text_modal" ).html( "<?=$text_modal_1?>" );
```

E assim você segue uma lógica pra cada.

Answer (score 1):

Faça o seguinte...

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="modaModal('<?php echo $title_modal; ?>', '<?php echo $text_modal; ?>');">Click me (seubotao)</a>

function mudaModal(titulo, texto) {
        $(".classeQueChamaSeuModal").click(); // para chamar seu modal
        $(".title_modal").html(titulo); //muda conteudo do titulo
        $(".text_modal").html(texto); //muda conteudo do texto
    }
```